# Vlookup from a table, column located on a different workbook

Tags: excel, vba

1. I am trying to do a Vlookup from a table that is located on a different workbook.

   - From a similar post in this forum I got a working formula
     `=VLOOKUP(E37,tblCosts[#All],COLUMN(tblCosts[Jun-17]),FALSE)`
   - I need to reference the table. How do I append the workbook name in the formula?
2. Once I have this formula working, how would I write it in VBA, reading the table name and the column name from cell values?

Comment: Why not open the other workbook, create the formula manually by point and click and look at the formula syntax? NB: I don't recommend doing a lookup over a table in an external workbook, it is slow.

Comment: You can't use a named table reference when looking up from another spreadsheet. You can query that table into your spreadsheet or you can use the cell references as an alternative.

Comment: If I write the formula manually, the formula generated refers the worksheet and not the table, I need to reference the table because while writing VBA, I only have Table and the Column name and not the worksheet name..

Comment: Is it possible to write the above vlookup in VBA and try to reference the worksheet name from the table.parent expression? It will still be a vlookup trying to operate on a table of a different workbook. I tried it and I was getting error, not sure about the exact cause of error, still..has anyone tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use this syntax (with the target workbook open):

`= VLOOKUP( Lookup_value, 'Target_Workbook_Name'!Table_Name[#Data], Col_index_num, FALSE )`

2. It has been tried before, but it would be very slow. However, since you are using VBA suggest working with the `ListObject` object, instead of trying to replicate the manner in which it is done manually.